# data-confirm-modal: The bootstrap modal plugin does not appear to be loaded

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I have been at this for a day now, i seem to be running in circels.

Rails 6 project with webpacker using bootstrap and jquery

ruby 2.7.4
rails 6.0.4.1
jquery 3.6.0
bootstrap 5.1.0
and data-confirm-modal 1.6.2

When the page loads the chrome debugger tells me: Uncaught Error: The bootstrap modal plugin does not appear to be loaded.

```
  if ($.fn.modal == undefined) {
    throw new Error("The bootstrap modal plugin does not appear to be loaded.");
  }
```

Jquery is working.
Also i can see $ and $.fn are defined.
modal is missing from the properties of $.fn

enviroment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
//require("turbolinks").start()  // gave reload bug... remove ?
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
//require("local-time").start()
require('jquery')

//import "./gems.js.erb"  # needs bundle exec rails webpacker:install:erb !
//import "./direct_uploads"

require('jquery-ui')

require('bootstrap')

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

import 'data-confirm-modal'
```

What am i missing ?

Found the problem... with help of data-confirm_model.
[See link](https://github.com/ifad/data-confirm-modal/issues/93)
https://github.com/ifad/data-confirm-modal/issues/93

Bootstrap 5 is not supported downgraded to version 4.

Comment: having the same issue, also my collapses are not working

Comment: I just updated my progress. Hope this helps you.